# How to create new build type react native android

Tags: react-native, android-productflavors

I have two 2 environments, dev and prod.
I am using product flavor to configure it, like this.

```
productFlavors {
  dev {
      minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
      applicationId 'XXX.XXX.XXX.dev'
      targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
      resValue "string", "build_config_package", "XXX.XXX.startup"
  }

  prod {
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    applicationId 'XXX.XXX.startup'
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    resValue "string", "build_config_package", "XXX.XXX.startup"
  }
}
```

For dev, I am using signingConfig signingConfigs.debug (debug.keystore) and for production I am using signingConfig signingConfigs.release (release.keystore).
So I want to add new build type maybe releaseDev, like this

```
release {
  signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
  minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
}
```

But when I execute assembledevReleasedev, its return so many error, something like this

```
Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'releaseDev' and found incompatible value 'release'
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a configuration for build type `releaseDev`. It should be somthing like this:

```java
    buildTypes {
        releaseDev {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
```

Take a look at [Build-variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

By the way, gradle product flavor isn't use for split environment purpose. Different flavor mean different application and there is no guarantee your `release` flavor match the behavior of `debug`. I highly recommend you to take a look at [React-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)